# Using Jenkins scp plugin to upload files from local machine to remote server.. getting error

Tags: jenkins-plugins

Error appears after using Jenkins scp plugin to upload files from local machine to remote server:

```
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building in workspace C:\Users\kishan_kumar01\.jenkins\jobs\TEST\workspace
[SCP] Connecting to 172.19.36.33
ERROR: Failed to upload files
2: No such file
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2289)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:1741)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:1758)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.stat(ChannelSftp.java:1715)
at be.certipost.hudson.plugin.SCPSite.upload(SCPSite.java:188)
at be.certipost.hudson.plugin.SCPRepositoryPublisher.perform(SCPRepositoryPublisher.java:218)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:720)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:185)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:665)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1754)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)
Build step 'Publish artifacts to SCP Repository' changed build result to UNSTABLE
Finished: UNSTABLE
```